# jQuery mobileでタブバーを実装したい

Tags: monaca, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

monacaのサンプルアプリのメモ帳にタブバーを実装したいです。（下に３つタブがついていてメモ帳アプリのトップ画面がタブの切り替え先にも表示され、メモ帳が１つのアプリに３つある感じ）

初心者なものでいろいろ調べてみたのですが、上手くタブバーとメモ帳を同じ画面に表示することができません。

回答のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: @豚吐露 　さん
回答ありがとうございます。
簡単にできる機能があるならぜひとも使いたいのですが、どのコードをどのように書き換えれば良いのかわからなくて．．．
再回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 表示することができないソースも記載してください。

Comment: @oTak  さん
ソースの意味をいまいち理解しておらず申し訳ないのですが、
サンプルのメモ帳アプリのコードと、インターネットでみつけたいくつかのタブバーのコードを使用しました。タブバーのコードはいろいろ使ってみましたが、メモサンプルコードのどこに書き加えて良いのかわかりませんでした。初歩的なことから教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

`TOP Page`の`</section>`のあとにナビゲーションバーをフッターとして追加してください。

```
<!-- TOP Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="TopPage">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Monaca Memo</h1>
        <a href="#AddPage" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-right">Add</a>
    </header>
    <section data-role="content">
        <ul id="TopListView" data-role="listview" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-split-icon="delete">
        </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- 以下を追加 -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Favorite</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ＠oTak
回答ありがとうございます。
タブを表示することができました。
重ねて質問で申し訳ありません。
タブのタップ先に新規のメモ帳をつけたいのですが、どこにコードを追記すれば良いのでしょうか。また、追記するコードはサンプルのメモ帳のコードをコピーしたもので良いのでしょうか…お忙しところと存じますが、回答いただけると幸いです。

Comment: @otm  まずはjQuery Mobileの本を購入するなどして基本的なところから学んだ方がよろしいかと思います。ナビゲーションバーの切り替えはどうすればよいか、メモ帳はどのようにして動作しているか、先に学ぶことはたくさんあると思いますが・・・